# Creating Binding from Code-Behind not working C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

[image: Screenshot]
I have the following code that creates a binding in code-behind. However, it does not seem to work (when the text in `PageMarginTextBox` is changed, nothing happens, and when the app is loaded, the `Padding` of `newPage` is not set to the text of `PageMarginTextBox`). To make matters worse, no `Exceptions` are thrown at all. All elements have been defined earlier on.

```
Binding pageMarginBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = PageMarginTextBox,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
};
newPage.SetBinding(ContentControl.PaddingProperty, pageMarginBinding);
//PageMarginTextBox.Text determines the Padding of newPage
```

How can I fix this? Any solutions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You wont get exception for binding errors, you will see the binding error details in the Output window when you are debugging. You can probably paste the error message to add more info to the question.

Comment: Sorry, there was no mention of 'Binding' in any of the windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Bind PaddingProperty to text. Padding property is of type `Thickness` and Text property is `String`.

I am not sure whether you want to bind padding / text, just giving you an idea if you want to bind the Padding.

```
Binding pageMarginBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = PageMarginTextBox,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Padding"),
};
newPage.SetBinding(ContentControl.PaddingProperty, pageMarginBinding);
```

Your problem is because you are trying to assign a `string` to a `Thickness`. In XAML the compiler internally translates the string "0,0,2,2" to `Thickness` object. But in code behind you have to write the code for the conversion yourself.

```
ThicknessConverter myThicknessConverter = new ThicknessConverter();
PageThickness= (Thickness)myThicknessConverter.ConvertFromString(PageMarginTextBox.Text);
```

Then you have to bind this to your control. Again this is only half the solution. You need to wire this up with the Binding.

```
private Thickness _pageThickness;
public Thickness PageThickness
{
get
 {
   return _pageThickness;
 }
set
 {
  _pageThickness = value;
  NotifyPropertyChanged("PageThickness");
 }
```

Then you probably can bind it in XAML

Comment: PageMarginTextBox.Text determines the Padding of newPage.

Comment: can you give an example text how it looks? e.g. 0,-2,2,0

Comment: @user5719584 it's a method **you** need to write to convert the string "0,-2,2,0" (or whatever the value is) to an actual `Thickness` object.